# MapStruct Mapper Bean not found

Tags: spring, maven, autowired, mapstruct, spring-bean

I am trying to create a mapper for my Capteur class :

Capteur:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.java;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Capteur {
    
    private Integer id;
    
    private Coordonnee coordonnee;
    
    private Integer intensite;
    
}
```

CapteurDto:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto;

import jakarta.annotation.Nonnull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CapteurDto {

    @Nonnull
    private Integer id;
    
    private CoordonneeDto coordonnee;
    
    private Integer intensite;
    
}
```

CapteurMapper :

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper;

import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.java.Capteur;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CapteurMapper {

    Capteur toCapteur(CapteurJpa capteurJpa);
    
    Capteur toCapteur(CapteurDto capteurDto);
    
    CapteurDto toCapteurDto(Capteur capteur);
    
    CapteurDto toCapteurDto(CapteurJpa capteurJpa);
    
    CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(Capteur capteur);
    
    CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(CapteurDto capteurDto);
    
    List<CapteurDto> toCapteurDto(List<CapteurJpa> capteurJpa);
    
}
```

And have use them all in a Controller with the help of a JpaRepo :

CapteurRepo :

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.repository;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;

@Repository
public interface CapteurRepository extends JpaRepository<CapteurJpa, UUID> {
    
}
```

CapteurController:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper.CapteurMapper;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.repository.CapteurRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/capteur")
public class CapteurController {

    @Autowired
    CapteurRepository capteurRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    CapteurMapper capteurMapper;
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<CapteurDto> getAllCapteur() {
        
        List<CapteurJpa> listJpa = capteurRepository.findAll();
        
        List<CapteurDto> listDto = capteurMapper.toCapteurDto(listJpa);
        
        return listDto;
                
    }
    
}
```

Strangely I get this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field capteurMapper in fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.controller.CapteurController required a bean of type 'fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper.CapteurMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper.CapteurMapper' in your configuration.
```

I saw that I had to add a mapstruct plugin and a compilerArg to say to use the springModel

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.projettresscientifique.reel</groupId>
    <artifactId>referentiel-reel</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>referentiel-reel</name>
    <description>WebServer du Simulateur</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It works when I do a mvn clean install

But the second there's a maven update (from Eclipse or exemple) it doesn't work again

Any help please ?

Thanks a lot !

**Edit 1:**

Even with the mvn clean install, I get my implementation:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.java.Capteur;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/*
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-12-14T16:58:02+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.3.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.1 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
*/
@Component
public class CapteurMapperImpl implements CapteurMapper {

    @Override
    public Capteur toCapteur(CapteurJpa capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Capteur capteur = new Capteur();

        return capteur;
    }

    @Override
    public Capteur toCapteur(CapteurDto capteurDto) {
        if ( capteurDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Capteur capteur = new Capteur();

        return capteur;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurDto toCapteurDto(Capteur capteur) {
        if ( capteur == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurDto capteurDto = new CapteurDto();

        return capteurDto;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurDto toCapteurDto(CapteurJpa capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurDto capteurDto = new CapteurDto();

        return capteurDto;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(Capteur capteur) {
        if ( capteur == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurJpa capteurJpa = new CapteurJpa();

        return capteurJpa;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(CapteurDto capteurDto) {
        if ( capteurDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurJpa capteurJpa = new CapteurJpa();

        return capteurJpa;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CapteurDto> toCapteurDto(List<CapteurJpa> capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CapteurDto> list = new ArrayList<CapteurDto>( capteurJpa.size() );
        for ( CapteurJpa capteurJpa1 : capteurJpa ) {
            list.add( toCapteurDto( capteurJpa1 ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when used

**Edit 2:**

It works after a mvn clean install

But when I try to map from List to List I get this error

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.id,
        c1_0.latitude,
        c1_0.longitude,
        c1_0.intensite 
    from
        capteurs c1_0
2022-12-14T17:15:52.846+01:00 ERROR 21820 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1306) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:408) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:30) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1568) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:483) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:194) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**Edit 3:**

With help I realised the problem is coming from the Lombook Getters and Setters.

I added it to the compiler in the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.projettresscientifique.reel</groupId>
    <artifactId>referentiel-reel</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>referentiel-reel</name>
    <description>WebServer du Simulateur</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I changed my build path to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeG20.png)

But I still get either the no bean found error if I just Maven update then launch.
Or my mapper just looks like this, so doesn't work, if I do a mvn clean install from cmd in the project:

```java
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.mapper;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.dto.CapteurDto;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.java.Capteur;
import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/*
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-01-03T09:50:24+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.3.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.1 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
*/
@Component
public class CapteurMapperImpl implements CapteurMapper {

    @Override
    public Capteur toCapteur(CapteurJpa capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Capteur capteur = new Capteur();

        return capteur;
    }

    @Override
    public Capteur toCapteur(CapteurDto capteurDto) {
        if ( capteurDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Capteur capteur = new Capteur();

        return capteur;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurDto toCapteurDto(Capteur capteur) {
        if ( capteur == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurDto capteurDto = new CapteurDto();

        return capteurDto;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurDto toCapteurDto(CapteurJpa capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurDto capteurDto = new CapteurDto();

        return capteurDto;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(Capteur capteur) {
        if ( capteur == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurJpa capteurJpa = new CapteurJpa();

        return capteurJpa;
    }

    @Override
    public CapteurJpa toCapteurJpa(CapteurDto capteurDto) {
        if ( capteurDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CapteurJpa capteurJpa = new CapteurJpa();

        return capteurJpa;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CapteurDto> toCapteurDto(List<CapteurJpa> capteurJpa) {
        if ( capteurJpa == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CapteurDto> list = new ArrayList<CapteurDto>( capteurJpa.size() );
        for ( CapteurJpa capteurJpa1 : capteurJpa ) {
            list.add( toCapteurDto( capteurJpa1 ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

I found a solution in the end, I was missing Lombok and Lombok-Mapstruct-Binding in my build part of my pom.xml

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: Your Java compiler is configured for Java8 not Java17. Also what you have here in your exception has nothing to do with Mapstruct but rather with Jackson. Your compiler also doesn't include the Lombok annotation processor which means the `@Getter` etc. are useless.

Comment: Hi I tried these fixes and it still doesn't work, the same problems happen. I might have done somehting wrong without realising, I have put in the edit what I have done. Thanks a lot for your help